# Best way to locate Find on List<T> with reflection

Tags: c#

I am locating the find method of List in C# with the single Expression type  parameter

I am using the following ( where T is a List, in my case a SubSonic IActiveRecord )

```
MethodInfo info = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Find" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
```

This works perfectly well, but feels clunky (especially the parameter count part) and I'm not sure how future proof it is.

Comment: IEnumerable expose one single method named GetEnumerator...

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox It also exposes many extension methods in C#3+ for use with LINQ

Comment: 1.GetMethod on IEnumerable<T> will never return theses. 2.None is called "Find" in the framework. 3.Look like you are searching on a List<T> as this one define a one parameter "Find" taking a predicate.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox Oh, you are correct. I always assumed it was an IEnumerable extension method, thanks. Question edited accordingly

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `GetMethod`?

Comment: @sepp2k It didn't work when I tried it. This is a first draft of the code, hence I'm here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When searching for methods using reflection I found that the most future-proof way is by searching exactly for the method, so not only the Count() is correct but I would also have checked both what is this parameter type and what is the return type of the function.

Comment: Thanks, less elegant, but more constrained and future proof, makes sense

Comment: Yes the case where you need to find a function with a Something<OtherThing<T>> paramter where T is a generic parameter of the parent class produce especially non elegant code. If someone took the time I guess that designing a small DSL for this could be possible.